# UI toolkit + programming language to develop linux applications

Tags: linux, gui, programming

Suggest good GUI designer tool with programming language for linux based application. For a developer who knows winform and C#.

Don't want to use mono on linux to run .net application on linux.
I have heard about GTK+ and Qt. What will be good for me.

found the link, which mention so many options?
http://linuxmafia.com/faq/Devtools/ides.html

Comment: You have heard about some *UI toolkits*, not "GUI designer tools". Nor programming languages. If you come from some Windows circles where people usually bundle language, UI design and text editor together, your confusion is understandable. But please be clear about what *exactly* are you looking for, and avoid expressions such as "best", go for "a good". You want suggestions, not a flame war, and "best" is something that seldom exists. Do you want a suggestion of a programming language to use? A suggestion of a toolkit? A suggestion of some WYSIWYG UI design tool? Of a text editor?

Comment: Why people send down vote without knowing the requirements or clarifications, although they option to edit the question or add comments to clarify more.  Budy help required, not a down vote.

Comment: People are downvoting because "suggest a ___ for me" is counter to the spirit of the site. It's similar to shopping recommendations: see http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for alternative of winform for C# in Linux, please look at the post on stackoverflow
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3693656/alternative-to-winforms-that-can-be-easily-used-with-c-sharp-and-net

Or search google for the same.

Answer (score 0):

Many people in the Linux world frown upon C# and the whole .net stuff. Consider using Python with its Gnome or Qt (KDE) bindings. For Gnome, there is glade to design the GUI, which is mostly independent from the program behind it.